# Word doesn't want to open hyperlinks, and I can't find the policy setting

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-8.1, hyperlink, windows-rt

So I have a Surface RT (running Windows RT 8.1), and I have some Word documents with links in them. The thing is, they don't work. When I try to activate one, this happens instead:

[image: "Your organization's policies are preventing us from completing this action for you. For more info, please contact your help desk."]

It's kind of annoying.

This is a personal device, so I *am* the organisation - and after much spelunking and web-searching, I still can't find the relevant policy, which means I can't change it. Is it talking about Group Policy or something else entirely? Is this a[nother] Windows RT limitation, or some obscure switch I haven't found yet, or...?

Comment: Is Internet Explorer your default browser? Here's a (possibly) related Microsoft article: [Hyperlinks are not working in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049/en-us).

Comment: @and31415 This is Windows RT, so Internet Explorer is literally the only option.

Comment: When a browser is the default one, it should be associated to the HTTP/HTTPS protocols and other extensions such as HTML. It turns out the article I linked did contain the solution you were looking for, which confirms the issue wasn't related to group policies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version; Try resetting you default browser settings, or reinstalling it if possible.

Long version; click below

http://www.slipstick.com/problems/this-operation-has-been-cancelled-due-to-restrictions/

Comment: The registry fix to `HKCR\.html` (`@="htmlfile"`) worked for me. (The culprit was Notepad++ rather than another browser, but the fix was the same.) Thanks for digging that up! I probably never would have found it otherwise - it was under the title of an older version of the error message... *\*sigh\**

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 0):

Set `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm]` and `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm]` default values to `"htmlfile"`

You can create a `"fixHTMLfile.reg"` like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm]
@="htmlfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html]
@="htmlfile"
```